# A few questions about how a Wordpress site is displayed in search engine results

Tags: html, wordpress

I have unchecked the box that says "discourage search engines" that I used when building my Wordpress website.

Since then, Google search results have stopped displaying a message that a description was not available because of my robots.txt file, but I'm a little confused at the results since it has started displaying the details of my website.

I want to get this right as soon as I can, because I know that Google can take a long time to update its search results.

So first of all, I've filled out the two fields in the Wordpress options as follows:

[image]

I have noticed that different browsers display the results differently, sometimes even the same browser on a different device like a mobile phone.

These are two of the results I'm getting:

**On Google search (mobile phone)**
This just pulls in all of the menu hyperlinks rather than adding the description I've written. 
[image]

**On Yahoo search**
The Yahoo result takes the description / bio from the about page, rather than using the one I've written in the box in the Wordpress settings.
[image]

I was under the impression that search engines break up the info given in Wordpress as shown in the diagram below. I'm not sure why there is so much variation in the different browsers / devices.
[image]

So I'm wondering the following –

1) Have I got the right idea regarding the way these Wordpress option fields should be displayed in Google search results?

2) If I have, then why might they not be displaying correctly? It's been over a week since I updated them to how they are written in my screenshot of the General Settings fields below.

3) If I were to leave these fields blank, would my meta tags in my `<head>`
take care of these instead? By these I mean –

`<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>`

and `<meta name="description" content="description goes in here..." />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I googled the name I was shown the About-section.

Google (and other search engines, but especially Google) wants to show relevant information to the user. Not what you want the user to see, but what might be usefull for the user, related to his search term and probably previous searches as well.

When someone is searching for the name of this person they probably want to know something about this person so I guess that is why Google is displaying the About-section. Or the user might want to see what is available on the site, that is why all the navigation links are shown in other cases.

Adding `<meta name="description" content="<?php echo get_bloginfo('description') ?>" />` might help you, but it probably will not be shown for each and every user. The search engine is always free to ignore that.

Comment: Hmm, it would make sense so you could be right. What I don't understand though, is why the same search engine is displaying different results on different devices.

Comment: Like I said, it's trying to give the user the information he probably needs. I guess having to do less clicks is more important for mobile users. At least in Google's opinion.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks for your explanation. One last thing – the description that's echoed in the meta tag in your answer, will that pull the information that I've entered into the "tagline" field above, providing the search engine will allow?

Comment: It should, I didn't test it, just quickly looked up how to get the tagline from wordpress.